# Value of variable is "undefined" and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a problem with my program - "this.imageManager.get("cowboy")" give back "undefined" and I don't know why.

1.There is code for ImageMenager constructor

```
function ImageManager(placeholderDataUri) {
  this._images = {};
  if (placeholderDataUri) {
    this._placeholder = new Image();
    this._placeholder.src = placeholderDataUri;
  }
}

_p = ImageManager.prototype;

_p.load = function(images, onDone, onProgress) {
  // The images queue
  var queue = [];
  for (var im in images) {
    queue.push({
      key: im,
      path: images[im]
    });
  }
  if (queue.length == 0) {
    onProgress && onProgress(0, 0, null, null, true);
    onDone && onDone();
    return;
  }

  var itemCounter = {
    loaded: 0,
    total: queue.length
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
    this._loadItem(queue[i], itemCounter, onDone, onProgress);
  }
};

_p._loadItem = function(queueItem, itemCounter, onDone, onProgress) {
  var self = this;
  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    self._images[queueItem.key] = img;
    self._onItemLoaded(queueItem, itemCounter, onDone, onProgress, true);
  };

  img.onerror = function() {
    self._images[queueItem.key] = self._placeholder ? self._placeholder : null;
    self._onItemLoaded(queueItem, itemCounter, onDone, onProgress, false);
  };
  img.src = queueItem.path;
};

_p._onItemLoaded = function(queueItem, itemCounter, onDone, onProgress, success) {
  itemCounter.loaded++;
  onProgress && onProgress(itemCounter.loaded, itemCounter.total, queueItem.key, queueItem.path, success);
  if (itemCounter.loaded == itemCounter.total) {
    onDone && onDone();
  }
};

/**
 * Returms the loaded image by the given value
 * @param key image alias
 */
_p.get = function(key) {
  return this._images[key];
};
```

2. There is a cod of Renderer constructor

```
function Renderer() {
  var self = this;
  this.readyForDrawing = false;

  //przygotowanie imageManager do pracy 
  this.imageManager = new ImageManager();
  this.imageManager.load({
    "cowboy": "cowboy.png"
  }, this._change());
}

_p = Renderer.prototype;

_p.draw = function(ComponentObj) {
  var object = ComponentObj;
  alert(this.imageManager.get("cowboy")); //there is alert which display    "undefined"
  ctx.drawImage(this.imageManager.get("cowboy"), object.x, object.y, object.width, object.height);
};

_p._change = function() {
  this.readyForDrawing = true;
};
```

I create object renderer and call function renderer.draw() when renderer.readyForDrawing has true value but then an error occurs -

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'

The value of `this.imageManager.get("cowboy")` is undefined and I don't know why (I was using function ImageManager for a while and everything was fine).

Comment: Are you waiting for the image to load before attempting to draw it?

Comment: You're calling `this._change()` immediately instead of passing a function that invokes it later.

Comment: @Mike C  Yes, I do. The second argument in imageManager.load() function is name of function that is called after loading an image

Comment: @squint I call that function immediately after the image is loaded. Is that causing a problem?

Comment: You're calling it immediately as you try to pass it to `.load()`. So instead of passing a function, you're passing the return value of `_change()`, which is `undefined`.

Comment: ^ In other words, you need to pass `this._change` (well, really `this._change.bind(this)` so you get the right binding) to `this.imageManager.load` instead of `this._change()`. What you're doing now is calling `this._change()` *immediately* and passing `undefined` to the `load` function.

Comment: @squint So I must pass a function that invokes another with setTimeout()?

Comment: @Mike C Thank you, You're my hero. :D

Comment: @squint Thank you as well, this forum is great.

Comment: @daniel432: The technique you're using inside `_loadItem` where you have a `self` variable that the code in the anonymous functions references is solving the same problem you're experiencing. You even seem to have started to anticipate this in that `var self = this;` was created in `Renderer`. As Mike pointed out, `.bind()` can also be used to deal with this, but if you were to follow the same pattern you were using *(not saying you should)*, you'd pass `function() { self._change() }` instead of `this.change()`.

Comment: @squint I changed <code>this._change()</code> to <code>this._change.bind(this)</code> and that doesn't work. After that I changed this to <code>function(){self._change()}</code> and that doesn't work as well. Have you idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like you're not adding anything to the `_images` object until the `img.onload` callback has run, at which point you add the cowboy `self._images[queueItem.key] = img;`. So if you're calling `rendered.draw()` immediately after you've created it, then it's running before the image has a chance to load, and therefore before the item has been added to `_images`. So either add the cowboy to the `_images` immediately instead of in the callback, or don't call `.draw()` until you've verified that the images have loaded.

Comment: @squint Thank you, I changed that code in _p._loadItem() function to a  `p._loadItem = function(queueItem, itemCounter, onDone, onProgress) {
 var self = this;
 var img = new Image();
 this._images[queueItem.key] = img;
 img.onload = function() {
  self._onItemLoaded(queueItem, itemCounter, onDone, onProgress, true);
 };   `
and alert give back a "object HTMLImageElement" so it's, but Image don't show up (there isn't any logs in console). And one more time i don't understand why. Have you any ideas?

Comment: @daniel432: Not sure. Try putting some `console.log()` calls here and there if you haven't already so that you can see what's running and what's not.